# Can you automatically number each face of a 3d model?

Tags: texturing

Is there a way to number the face of your 3d models automatically?
I want to do somthing simler to this - [image]

But automatically  and on more complex shapes.

Comment: Is  this a texture painting question? Do you have experience with the Python programming language?  Do you want well known type faces as opposed to hand drawn?

Comment: Blender can show you the face numbers as a built-in, non artistic display

Comment: Particles and Duplifaces .. may be an option.  All these items can be searched  here at BSE.

Comment: The number of vertices, planes etc should be on the info bar.